# Selenium / WatiN - Automating Embedded IE inside Desktop Application

Tags: internet-explorer, automation, embedded-browser

I am trying to automate functional test of web application that launches in the embedded IE.
I am using white automation framework to reach the point till application opens the web app in embedded IE. I am looking for a way to get the hook to embedded IE , so that i can drive the workflow. How do i do that? I know its not possible thru Selenium /Watin out of the box , let me know other ways to do it.

thanks
J

Answer (score 0):

Try Autoit. It has pretty functional tool called "window info".